# Power Supply Layout

Tags: power-supply, pcb, pcb-design, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

Edit: Thank you everyone for the amazing feedback! I am definitely going to do more research and make the suggested improvements :)

I have just completed a 24V, 120W power supply layout, and I would like some feedback on my work. This is only my second ever layout, so I am sure there is a lot I can improve on.

I have already done some research on design for manufacturing (DFM) rules, and I even reached out to a fabrication house for help on setting up the DFM PCB design rules.

I am aware that there are other design considerations such as thermal performance, and signal integrity, but I do not know how to begin learning about those. Any feedback would be much appreciated, thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You might want to add a schematic so potential responders can follow how the circuit works, where the important current loops are, etc...

Comment: That's a good idea! I have a copy of the smart pdf, but I do not know how to attach it :/

Comment: There seems to be a mistake in the schematic. D104/R120/C110 are not going to do much configured like that.

Comment: Excellent catch! I have just fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Check your clearances on the mains input .Remove your copper islands .I could go on and on but I wont .

Comment: There are a number of problems - unfortunately neither the schematic or pcb are viable. There's no input filtering, no EMC protection, no Y capacitor across the transformer. I'd suggest you get a piece of consumer gear, say a 55" tv and have a look at how they design and layout their power supply or get a psu brick from the likes of Meanwell et al and see how they do it. These psus are highly cost and compliance engineered, so it would be wise to follow their lead.

Comment: I can provide both of them to you!

Comment: @Autistic what is a good threshold for a copper island? i.e. below x mm^2, I should remove it.

Comment: I think you misread 'viable' vs 'visible'. Both your schematic and pcb have critical problems - you can build it, but I doubt it will work as intended. My advice is to do some research - I think you underestimate the amount of engineering that goes into a switched mode power supply.

Comment: @Kartman ok, thanks! I have no intention of building this thing. I am slowly progressing - trying to make each power supply better than the last one. I will research the stuff you mentioned, and then I will make a whole new power supply, hopefully one that is better :)

Comment: Because of the high voltages involved, you normally don't see copper fills on this style of psu. Understand the concept of clearance and creepage distance - your pcb violates these virtually everywhere. Choice of components is critical - most of your resistors look way too small - did you check their voltage rating? Wattage? How long will your output electrolytic capacitor last? You might need to use a number of capacitors in parallel. As I previously mentioned - look at a commercial psu - every component is there for a reason and is carefully chosen and cost engineered.

Comment: To add a minor stylistic complaint to the major functional concerns: your component designator scheme is a little unwieldy; you don't need to use the sheet-separated style when you only have one sheet. And the way you're positioning the designators when you have multiple devices right next to each other is quite hard to read. This, of course, doesn't affect the function of the board and you have bigger problems to deal with, but you should at least try to avoid putting designators right next to each other like that.